# How to track values in prolog?

Tags: prolog

In this prolog example, you can use recursion to find arbitrary Z values to ultimately check if someone is someone's ancestor. However, what if you wanted to get a list of the Z's to know the chain of parents that led to the ancestor? How can you output that?

Thanks

```
parent(john,paul).             /* paul is john's parent */  

parent(paul,tom).              /* tom is paul's parent */

parent(tom,mary).              /* mary is tom's parent */       

ancestor(X,Y):- parent(X,Y).   /* someone is your ancestor if there are your parent */

ancestor(X,Y):- parent(X,Z), /* or somebody is your ancestor if they are the parent */
    ancestor(Z,Y). /* of someone who is your ancestor */
```

http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/recursion.html

Comment: Much more important than explicit tracking is to understand the termination properties of your program. Your program terminates **never**. See [tag:failure-slice] for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can try building a list like this:

```
anclist(X, X, []). /* Stop when you get to the end*/
anclist(X, Y, [H|T]) :- parent(X, H), ancestor(H, Y), anclist(H, Y, T).
```

You call this:

```
 anclist(john, mary, X).
```

and get:

```
 X = [paul, tom, mary]
```